# How to display very long user name on text file of mobile (Android/iOS)

Tags: android, ios, testing

Please help me.

I'm creating test case to test for application on mobile (Android/iOS). 
Screen only display at land scape status.

In case, In database have account with user = long text (ex: HaPhamHaPhamHaPhamHaPhamHaPhamHaPhamHaPhamHaPhamHaPhamHaPham).

When open app, will load data from DB to view. With this case, text field to view user can not display full text.

In this case, how to show reasonable?

Thanks you.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Requirement as below: Not multi line, not scroll, and screen only display land portrait status.

Comment: @Ha Pham What case you want to test here?